# Implementing the Harvey van der Hoeven algorithm

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, implementation

I am doing a project to confirm if the time complexity of harvey-van der hoeven algorithm is O(nlogn) as stated in the paper, by actually giving two very big number inputs and see how much time it takes to multiply them.
So, I need to understand and implement the algorithm first, but I can't find any source codes, pseudo-codes, or any helpful article to understand it.
I tried to implement it myself, but I got stuck on especially the mathemetics in the algorithm.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Drop the idea, this is my best advice. You can only observe the asymptotic behavior for astronomical values of N that cannot be handled by existing computers, nor even future ones. Also consider that the method is so complicated that one can seriously doubt that it will ever be programmed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Harvey & van der Hoeven 2019 algorithm (huge integer multiplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646578/understanding-harvey-van-der-hoeven-2019-algorithm-huge-integer-multiplicatio)